# Android Rotation Hide some Widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, autorotate

this my xml file of an activity. It works well except in the case of rotation. In my mobile, if AutoRotation is enabled, then the screen is also rotated. During rotation it doesn't show the Button named "Exit". I've tried to scroll to bottom, but I can't able to scroll.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

<AbsoluteLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/slogon"      
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="481dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FF0000"     android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="EXISTINGFARMER" android:layout_x="161dip" android:layout_y="157dip"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FF0000" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="NEW FARMER" android:layout_x="34dip" android:layout_y="157dip"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FF0000" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/btn_exit" android:layout_width="100dip" android:text="EXIT" android:layout_x="105dip" android:layout_y="233dip"></Button>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="40dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFEA00" android:id="@+id/heading" android:text="S.V.Sugar Mills" android:layout_x="29dip" android:layout_y="14dip"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subheading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="38dp"
    android:layout_y="97dp"
    android:text="The New and Old Farmer Details."
    android:textColor="#0000A0"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I didn't understand the mistake, I someone know how to scroll during rotation, please help help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to put your all the widgets in scrollview if you want to support scroll in portrait or landscape mode.

Please use scrollview . Scrollview supports only one direct child. So you need to take relative layout or linear layout as child of scrollview, put all your widget controll in that child layout.

Look [here](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/02/scrollview-tutorial-android-ui.html) for scrollview tutorial.

Comment: @ling.s i updated my answer . I put one link for scrollview example. From there you can get better idea how to use scrollview.

Comment: can i use scroll view in absolute layout?

Comment: Now Absolute Layout is depreciated so please use Linear or Relative Layout. Make Scrollview as Parent and put all your code in scrollview . (Example copy your code from Absolute layout and put it in scrollview)

Comment: @ling.s i updated your code . please copy your code from your question and run it/